# Rewrite Url with apache2

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I'm experimenting with CodeIgniter PHP framework, this framework works like:

`http://localhost:7777/~dhalsim/ci/index.php/blog`

So, I tried to remove `index.php` part from there. So far I do these:

1. make `$config['index_page'] = "index.php";` to `$config['index_page'] = "";`
2. make `$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";` from `$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";`
3. enable apache mod_rewrite by "`a2enmod rewrite`"
4. put a .htaccess file to `/ci` directory:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
   ```
5. And of course restart apache server

Here is my apache logs with these configurations:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (3) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/blog -> blog
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (3) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'blog'
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (4) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] RewriteCond: input='/~dhalsim/ci/blog' pattern='^system.*' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (3) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/blog -> blog
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (3) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'blog'
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (4) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/blog' pattern='!-f' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (4) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/blog' pattern='!-d' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (2) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] rewrite 'blog' -> 'index.php?/blog'
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (3) split uri=index.php?/blog -> uri=index.php, args=/blog
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (3) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (2) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] trying to replace prefix /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/ with /
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2009:02:21:41 +0300] [localhost/sid#7f48e8ad2968][rid#7f48e8e634c8/initial] (1) [perdir /home/dhalsim/public_html/ci/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

---

Here is the result in Firefox:

> 404 Not Found:
>   The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

---

So, what should I do (or where am I wrong) to get work these URLs?
`http://localhost:7777/~dhalsim/ci/blog/` instead of `http://localhost:7777/~dhalsim/ci/index.php/blog/`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i resolve it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|flash|css|js|robots\.txt|downloads)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then in the config.php file

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost:7777/~dhalsim/ci/";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

**UPDATE**

In the routes.php file:

```
//Point to default controller
$route['default_controller']    = "site/home"; //Set to your controller

// Point to the right controller
$routing_array = array(
            'blog' => 'site/blog',
        ); // set to your blog controler
```

Comment: $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";

Comment: actually my $route['default_controller'] is
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); 

and $route['default_controller'] = "blog"; //my controller
but didn't get what $routing_array is for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

In order for this to work you should setup your CodeIgniter app on a different port or use /etc/hosts to give it a simple Vhost (`127.0.0.1 ci` and `http://ci:7777/` with Apache set to use the `ci` vhost.). Then you can set the base url to `/` and not worry about it. Otherwise you're going to have to deal with confusing directory issues and mod_rewrite.